# Populate an array with column from a database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to populate an array with some datas taken from a database. My DB Table looks like this:

```
Tablename

ID | PROFILEID  |    PAGEID   | VOTE
------------------------------------
1  | 1563187610 | /example.php| 1
2  | 1563187610 | /example.php| 2
3  | 1946357685 | /example.php| 1
------------------------------------
```

And with every code I try to use I always get an array that looks like: `Array ( )`

This is the code that I use to populate the array:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT FROM `Tablename`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$var = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $var[] = $row['PROFILEID'];
}

print_r($var);
$conn->close();

?>
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Tablename`";
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $conn);

$var = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $var[] = $row['PROFILEID'];
}

print_r($var);
```

still gives the Array() problem.

If I put the "`or die(mysqli_error($conn))`" it doesn't say anything and I have a blank screen

**SOLVED**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}



$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Tablename`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$var = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $var[] = $row["PROFILEID"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

print_r ($var);
$conn->close();
```

Comment: You need a placeholder in your query SELECT * FROM `Tablename`

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. That won't work.

Comment: Don't assume that your queries will work. You also should add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: you simply assumed that your query succeeded, which it didn't, because you have a syntax error in the sql. **NEVER** assume success with DB queries. There's exactly ONE way for a query to succeed, and a near infinite number of reasons for it to fail. You're coding as if `1:infinity` odds are in your favor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `mysqli` functions instead of `mysql_`* . Also, you need the `*` in your `SELECT` statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Tablename`";
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $conn);

$var = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $var[] = $row['PROFILEID'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try doing this:

```
$var = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $var[] = $row['PROFILEID'];
}
```

Or:

```
$var = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $var[] = $row['PROFILEID'];
}
```